# how to read a php json decoded array

Tags: php

I get the following string when I use `$JSON = var_dump(json_decode($MyJSON, true));`
If I echo $JSON:-

```
array(1) {
["test"]=> array(2) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
        ["subject"]=> array(2) {
            ["type"]=> string(10) "blank node" ["val"]=> string(4) "_:b0" 
        } 
        ["predicate"]=> array(2) {
            ["type"]=> string(3) "IRI" ["val"]=> string(47) "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type" 
        }
        ["object"]=> array(2) {
            ["type"]=> string(3) "IRI" ["val"]=> string(25) "http://schema.org/WebPage" 
        }
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        ["subject"]=> array(2) {
            ["type"]=> string(10) "blank node" ["val"]=> string(4) "_:b0" 
        }
        ["predicate"]=> array(2) {
            ["type"]=> string(3) "IRI" ["val"]=> string(28) "http://schema.org/breadcrumb" 
        }
        ["object"]=> array(2) {
            ["type"]=> string(10) "blank node" ["val"]=> string(4) "_:b1" 
        }
    } 
 }
}
```

what if I want to `echo $JSON->test[0]->predicate->val` what is the right syntax? Sorry I am a beginner. It would be a big help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess var_dump is not needed here...

Comment: try `$JSON['test'][0]['predicate']['val']`

Comment: Read the documentation to find out what `var_dump(json_decode(..., true))` actually does.

Comment: @PhilCross I tried echo $JSON["test"][0]["predicate"]["val"]; It prints the whole data I mean same output as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove var_dump

```
$JSON = var_dump(json_decode($MyJSON, true));
```

So $JSON becomes

```
$JSON = json_decode($MyJSON, true);
```

You will then be able to access the variable required via

```
$JSON['test'][0]['predicate']['val'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try to do `json_decode($MyJson)` without true as second parameter? This will return a STD object which should resemble the way you want to access the json object. See the PHP documentation for more info (second parameter $assoc=true means that it will be converted to an associative array): [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)